# Can I ignore "Incompatible Gradle Versions" lint check if Gradle overrides transtivie dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, lint, android-lint

I just violated this lint check:

> Incompatible Gradle Versions ../../build.gradle: All
>   com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.3.1, 25.2.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and
>   com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0

Some of my transitive dependencies are surely not updated to the latest support version. However I set the the support libs as first-level dependencies, at the latest version in my app `build.gradle` file. I can even see that Gradle is overriding all of these dependencies:

```
$ ./gradlew app:dependencies | grep 25.2.0

|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
```

Is there anything I have to worry about, or can I safely ignore this lint error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't overriding every dependency: `com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0` is not being updated to `25.3.1`.

You should add `compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"` to ensure everything is on the same version.

Comment: Ahh right under my nose. I misread the indentations in the grep. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to get a new gradle version. Even though it overrides it, it will not work. I recently published an android app and had to get a new gradle version. You can download it here https://gradle.org/releases